# Does using the Amazon FPS marketplace option require senders to have Amazon accounts?

Tags: amazon-fps

This is a pretty basic question. It seems like if I use the FPS marketplace option with the CBUI to obtain payment authorization from the sender, this requires that the sender (who is a consumer on a web site) have an Amazon account in order to pay. Or can they enter credit card information without needing to have an Amazon account?

I love the option that consumers can use their Amazon accounts to pay for things, but I can not make this a requirement for all consumers. I also love the flexibility I get with FPS, but it seems like that only works for consumers that are willing to use their Amazon account.

Is there any way to get the benefits of the FPS marketplace features, without requiring the sender/consumer to have an Amazon account?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes. This I learned after calling them and asking them myself. In fact, Checkout by Amazon, Simple Pay, and FPS all require the customer to have (or then create) an Amazon account.